# How do I solve the error which I get when I try installing custom extension on TYPO3 ver. 10?

Tags: controller, annotations, typo3, repository, typo3-10.x

I have installed TYPO3 ver. 10. I have a custom extension which runs perfectly on TYPO3 ver. 9. I want this customised extension to be compatible with the latest TYPO3 ver. 10. But I get an error after installation.Below mentioned is the error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@inject" in property ABC\EXTSocial\Controller\SocialController::$socialRepository was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

Could somebody help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 13):

`@inject` annotation is deprecated since TYPO3 `ver.: 9` and removed since `ver.: 10`.

You should use `@TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject` instead.

[Look at the Change Log `#82869`](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Feature-82869-ReplaceInjectWithTYPO3CMSExtbaseAnnotationInject.html)